# using Python to search for keywords in pdf

Tags: python, regex, pdf

I'm searching for  keywords in a pdf file so I'm trying to search for /AA or /Acroform like the following:

```
import re
l = "/Acroform "
s = "/Acroform is what I'm looking for"
if re.search (r"\b"+l.rstrip()+r"\b",s):
    print "yes"
```

why I don't get "yes". I want the "/" to be part of the keyword I'm looking for if it exist.
any one can help me with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\b` *only* matches in between a `\w` (word) and a `\W` (non-word) character, or vice versa, or when a `\w` character is at the edge of a string (start or end).

Your string starts with a `/` forward slash, a *non word* character, so `\W`. `\b` will never match between the start of a string and `/`. Don't use `\b` here, use an explicit negative look-behind for a word character :

```
re.search(r'(?<!\w){}\b'.format(re.escape(l)), s)
```

The `(?<!...)` syntax defines a negative look-behind; like `\b` it matches a position in the string. Here it'll only match if the preceding character (if there is any) is *not* a word character.

I used string formatting instead of concatenation here, and used `re.escape()` to make sure that any regular expression meta characters in the string you are searching for are properly escaped.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> l = "/Acroform "
>>> s = "/Acroform is what I'm looking for"
>>> if re.search(r'(?<!\w){}\b'.format(re.escape(l)), s):
...     print 'Found'
... 
Found
```

Comment: it gives me "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: @user3569815: are you certain you copied the text correctly? It works fine for me.

Comment: yes absolutely it worked, but what if I have a group of key words, some of them contain "/", I tried  to apply the code above on my code but it doesn't give me the right answer

Comment: @user3569815: I have no idea what your group contains, but it'll normally work with and without slashes at the start. You could have a similar problem with the `\b` at the end; use `(?!\w)` instead to add a negative look-ahead.

Comment: @Marjin Pieters when I applied it on a text like the example above it works fine. but with the pdf file it doesn't work.
could I send you my code and the file am doing the test on it if it possible ?

Comment: PDF text is not always linear in the file; also see the proposed dupe target.